# Why does document.embeds return collection of functions in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, embed

**document.forms**, **document.images** etc return collections of NORMAL elements, but **document.embeds** return collection of anonymous functions - WHY?

In Google Chrome - bug:

[image]

In FireFox all Okay:

[image]

Full webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<embed src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf"></embed>
<embed></embed>
<form id="someForm"></form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you got a page with embeds on that we can look at?

Comment: which browser? because [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-embeds) clearly states that document.embeds should be a HTMLCollection (like document.forms is in your pretty picture)

Comment: Browser - Google chrome